# NVidia GeForce 9800GTX+ cooler spins at 100% speed all time

Tags: drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

My Leadtek PX9800+ stopped to control cooler rotation speed this night and I don't see why. I played Skyrim and then left the PC playing radio for the night. Cooler worked OK at that moment. When I woke up in the morning, the cooler was blowing at full speed even on Windows desktop (and it's really very noisy: about 35 dB I think). The driver is latest (285.62, got it from Windows Update), no modifications of software of hardware occurred in last two days.

All tweakers and monitoring utilities which I tried to use (SiSoftware Sandra, RivaTuner, EVGA Precision, GPU-Z) display that there's automatic fan control enabled (and speed is 35%) and even when trying to manually override the settings, cooler doesn't slow down or change it speed at all. All other parameters, such as frequencies and voltages, seem to be normal. Temperature is just 47 C (of course, it's blowing at 100%!).

Reflashing BIOS didn't do the trick. Cooler blows both in Windows and in BIOS (before OS loading).

Does it mean I have to replace my card of there's something left to try?

**Updates:**

- Maybe it's a bit dusty, but suddenly changing it's sound from barely noticeable to vacoom-cleaner-like seems to be unlikely :)
- I don't run dual cards, only one is present.

Comment: It isn't dusty at all is it? Maybe just needs a little blowing out?

Comment: Are you running dual cards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the fan connection. There should be three wires, return, power and sense. If the sense wire is disconnected for any reason (open circuit or a poorly seated plug) then the fan will be told to run at top speed by the control circuit.

Comment: That's may be the case, thank you! Any suggestions on how to actually check the connection (I mean the wire itself)?

Comment: If you don't have a DVM then not really. You could try a replacement fan of the same spec.

Answer (score 0):

And now the strange thing comes in: today it went back to normal mode and doesn't spin at maximum speed all the time. I did nothing with the card and stopped any manipulations with the software either. However it went back to normal and RivaTuner now can change fan speed too.

I believe it's unstable fan connection as @Tog mentioned, will check it if the problem will come up again.